# Dynamic Static Scope - Deep Binding Shallow Binding

Tags: scope

this exercise is driving me crazy. I mean, I know how Scope and Binding work but I can only understand easy examples. In this case, I'm not able to solve the exercise, it's too tricky.
For example,

```
1. {int x = 1;
2.   int y = 1;
3.   int f (int y) {
4.         x = y+x;
5.         return x}
6.   int g (int -> int h, int y) {
7.          int x = 2;
8.          y = f(x);
9.          return h(y)}
10.   int x = 3;
11.   y = g(f,x);}
```

what is the value of y in line 11 considering these cases?
Static Deep Binding
Dinamic Deep Binding
Dinaming Shallow Binding
Sorry for my english
Thank you

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this?

Comment: Static Deep Binding
g(f,x) in line 11:  x is 3 and f takes the environment with x=3. Then, in line 8 f takes 2, which means that in line 5 the returned value of x is 3?? (I've considered in line 4 x=1 and y=2, but I'm not sure about the value of x). Then in line 9 h takes y=3 and back again in line 4, x is 3 and y is 3, so the function returns 6.
Is this correct? 
Sorry I'm typing on the phone, I'm very slow.

Comment: Dinamic Deep Binding, y=7 ??
Shallow Deep Binding, y=8 ??
Anyway, I don't know if there is any difference beetween the f function called in line 8 and the h function called in line 9. Do they take the same environment? Also, why is there a second declaration of x in line 10? Would have been different if instead of int x=3 it was just x=3 ??